# How can I vertically center image in wp post

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a wordpress website and I want to verticlly center image with the text. For example can see the screenshot below. How can I adjuce my image and text like below with css.

The image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please use any of below CSS Classes:

```
.center{vertical-align: middle;}
 or 
.center{
transform:translate(0,50%);

}
```